# Mysql workbench timestamp change format

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table with a column in which are inserted timestamps.

exactTime : ' 2017-12-17 05:00:12 ' and i want to change this format into '2017-12-17 05:00'

i would need some help with this .

Comment: Mysql?  SQL Server SQLite?  I took a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `date_format` for this.

```
select date_format(your_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
from your_table;
```

[**Resource**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate to the nearest minute using:

```
select str_to_date('2017-12-17 05:00:12', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
```

To actually output without seconds, you need to convert back to a string.  Or just use string operations:

```
select left('2017-12-17 05:00:12', 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT date_format('2017-12-17 05:00:12','%Y-%m-%d %h:%i')